# Error Segmentation fault (core dumped) trabajando con C y assembly GAS

Tags: c, linux, ensamblador

estoy experimentando trabajar con C y ensamblador GAS, pero obtengo un error de Segmentation fault (core dumped). Estoy trabajando en linux.

Codigo C:

```
extern void _print(void);

void _start(int argc, char **argv) {

  _print();

}
```

Codigo Ensamblador GAS:

```
.global _print

.type _print, %function


.text

_print:

  mov $1, %rax

  mov $1, %rdi

  mov $msg, %rsi

  mov $12, %rdx

  syscall

  ret


.data

msg:

  .string "Hello World!"
```

Lo compilo de esta forma:

```
gcc -nostdlib -c main.c -o main.o
as printer.s -o printer.o
ld main.o printer.o -o result
```

Resultado:

```
 %./result
 Hello World!Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Este es el resultado de objdump -d result

```
result:     file format elf64-x86-64

Disassembly of section .text:

00000000004000e8 <_start>:
  4000e8:   55                      push   %rbp
  4000e9:   48 89 e5                mov    %rsp,%rbp
  4000ec:   48 83 ec 10             sub    $0x10,%rsp
  4000f0:   89 7d fc                mov    %edi,-0x4(%rbp)
  4000f3:   48 89 75 f0             mov    %rsi,-0x10(%rbp)
  4000f7:   e8 03 00 00 00          callq  4000ff <_print>
  4000fc:   90                      nop
  4000fd:   c9                      leaveq 
  4000fe:   c3                      retq   

00000000004000ff <_print>:
  4000ff:   48 c7 c0 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rax
  400106:   48 c7 c7 01 00 00 00    mov    $0x1,%rdi
  40010d:   48 c7 c6 00 10 60 00    mov    $0x601000,%rsi
  400114:   48 c7 c2 0c 00 00 00    mov    $0xc,%rdx
  40011b:   0f 05                   syscall 
  40011d:   c3                      retq
```

Y este el resultado de objdump -s result

```
result:     file format elf64-x86-64

Contents of section .text:
 4000e8 554889e5 4883ec10 897dfc48 8975f0e8  UH..H....}.H.u..
 4000f8 03000000 90c9c348 c7c00100 000048c7  .......H......H.
 400108 c7010000 0048c7c6 00106000 48c7c20c  .....H....`.H...
 400118 0000000f 05c3                        ......          
Contents of section .eh_frame:
 400120 14000000 00000000 017a5200 01781001  .........zR..x..
 400130 1b0c0708 90010000 1c000000 1c000000  ................
 400140 a8ffffff 17000000 00410e10 8602430d  .........A....C.
 400150 06520c07 08000000                    .R......        
Contents of section .data:
 601000 48656c6c 6f20576f 726c6421 00        Hello World!.   
Contents of section .comment:
 0000 4743433a 20285562 756e7475 20372e35  GCC: (Ubuntu 7.5
 0010 2e302d33 7562756e 7475317e 31382e30  .0-3ubuntu1~18.0
 0020 34292037 2e352e30 00                 4) 7.5.0.
```

Se supone que ese error pasa cuando se trata de acceder a una dirección de memoria, pero viendo el resultado de objdump no entiendo porque pasa, y lo mas raro es que pasa después de imprimir hello world!

Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

El problema es que, en la entrada a tu función `_start( )`, la pila **no es válida para retornar**.

Según `The Linux Kernel 2.4 Internals`, capítulo [`Process and Interrupt Management`](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/lki/lki-2.html), hay varias formas de *terminar* la ejecución de un proceso:

> 1. by making exit(2) system call;
> 2. by being delivered a signal with default disposition to die;
> 3. by being forced to die under certain exceptions;
> 4. by calling bdflush(2) with func == 1 (this is Linux-specific, for compatibility with old distributions that still had the 'update' line in /etc/inittab - nowadays the work of update is done by kernel thread kupdate).

Como ves, no se menciona nada sobre `hacer un ret desde la función de entrada`.

La explicación es que, antes de llamar a esa función, el *kernel* almacena en la pila ciertos datos, entre ellos los argumentos de entrada ( `argc` y `argv` ). Ese proceso resulta en una pila **no compatible** con la instrucción `ret`. Además, tampoco tienes *a donde* retornar: ¿ Al código del *kernel* desde el que se creó el proceso ?

Es fácil de ver con una pequeña modificación de tu código:

> código C

```
extern void _print(void);

void _start(int argc, char **argv) {

  _print();
  _print();
}
```

Ahora, compilamos, enlazamos, y ejecutamos ...

> Hello World!Hello World!Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Como ves, la cadena se ha escrito correctamente **2 veces**. Lo cual nos indica que el código *asm* es correcto, así como la llamada al mismo desde C y el posterior retorno.

La solución ya la habrás adivinado: no puedes terminar tu código con un `return` o un `ret`. **Has de llamar a la función `sys_exit` o `sys_exit_group`**. No tenemos mas que añadir una nueva función a tu código:

> Código C

```
extern void _print(void);
extern void _doexit(void);

void _start(int argc, char **argv) {
  _print();
  _doexit();
}
```

> Código *asm*

```
.global _print
.global _doexit

.text

_print:
  mov $1, %rax
  mov $1, %rdi
  mov $msg, %rsi
  mov $12, %rdx
  syscall

ret

_doexit:
  mov $18, %rdi
  mov $60, %rax
  syscall

.data

msg:
  .string "Hello World!"
```

Volvemos a compilar, enlazar y ejecutar ...

> as -o print.o print.s
> gcc -nostdlib -c -o main.o main.c
> ld -o test main.o print.o
> ./test
> echo $?

Con lo que obtenemos:

> Hello World!
> 18

Y puedes comprobar que el código de salida es el que nosotros indicamos en la llamada a `sys_exit`:

```
mov $18, %rdi
```